# Clarkson inequality for complex numbers

Tags: inequality, lp-spaces, convexity-inequality

Let $1<p<2$. I'm trying to prove the inequality

$$
|a+b|^q+|a-b|^q\leq 2\big( |a|^p + |b|^p \big)^{q-1}
$$
where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

Following [this paper](https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1415/math5011/MATH5011_Chapter_4.2014.pdf), I am able to prove the inequality for real $a,b$.

I'm missing the step to complex.

I have tried to set $x=|a+b|^2$ and $y=|a-b|^2$ (and other combinations) and then use the real inequality for $x,y$ with no success.

This is not exactly a duplicate of
[On the second Clarkson's inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/266532/on-the-second-clarksons-inequality)
because that one asked from a "from scratch" proof while I'm only asking for one step.

Comment: I found [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1607683/how-to-prove-clarksons-inequality) which makes the work. One can found a proof of the required Hölder inequalities [here](http://jf.burnol.free.fr/agregnormeslp.pdf) (in French). If you are interested, I wrote a fully detailed proof in [giulietta](http://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/giulietta.pdf) in the french part (search for "Clarkson").

Comment: I checked your document above (in French) and I think that the use of Holder's inequality in the proof of Clarkson's inequality (Lemma 27.136)is not done correctly there. The assumptions are $1<p<2$, thus the convex conjugate $q$ of $p$ is larger than $2$. Then you argue that $$\|(x+y, x-y\|^q_q\leq \Big(2^{1/q-1/2}\|x+y,x-y\|_2\big)^q$$ This is not quite right as $2<q$ (Holder's inequality goes in the opposite way: $0<r<s$ then $\|v\|_r\leq n^{1/r-1/2}\|v\|_s$

Comment: The inequality can be reduced to the real case by optimizing with respect to the angle between $a $ and $b$ , i.e. the argument of $\bar{a} b.$ The maximum of the left hand side is attained when the angle is $0$ or $\pi$ which means that one of the numbers is a real multiple of the other.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: that is indeed the case, and that is done for example in Hewitt and Stromberg. The issue that I want to raise with to the OP is that his proof in the real case in his notes (see link before) is not correct. The real case appears also in Hewitt-Stomber and in Makarov, et. al, Selected problems in analysis, using Calculus methods, which are rather messy and tricky in this case. I just wanted to present an alternative proof which uses Riesz interpolation (which is usually covered in courses of graduate analysis) which is rather slick.

Comment: @OliverDíaz I have just searched the net and found [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:981503/FULLTEXT01.pdf&ved=2ahUKEwiN9vTJxfj3AhXBlosKHedICFkQFnoECAgQAQ&usg=AOvVaw0trV4HuTl1yx03Pa5YtQXE) where there are several proofs including short ones based on one dimensional calculus.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Thanks is a very nice paper. thanks for sharing. Method (2) is basically what I described. The idea appears in a paper by Boas. If you have time, check the link that the OP has to his notes (first comment of his) and check his proved of Clarkson inequalities for $1<p<2$. Like I said, I think his proof is in error. Since his document is open for everybody, I would just like the OP to be aware of that so that he puts an errata. Best ODE.

Comment: @OliverDíaz Ok. I will take a look at that paper. What does ODE mean ? I am bad in american slang. Anyway, best ODE.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: ODE are my initials, funnily enough, it is also the acronym for  Ordinary Differential Equations. While in grad school long time ago, may people would point that out.

Comment: @OliverDíaz  Best, RS

Comment: @Oliver Díaz Well spotted. I will replace the whole by Ryszard Szwarc's answer. Thanks.

Comment: @LaurentClaessens I have checked [giulietta](http://laurent.claessens-donadello.eu/pdf/giulietta.pdf) . As Oliver Diaz observed, there is an error: $27.519e$ does not imply $27.519f$ as the Holder inequality goes the wrong way. Besides, there is a misprint in $27.519d,$ the factor in front should be equal $2$, but the next line is correct,

Comment: If is "fixed" by replacing the whole proof by  Ryszard Szwarcs'one. I'll see if the same error is not [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1607823/294061) too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's assume for simplicity that $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0.$  Then $$\displaylines{|a+b|^2=|a|^2+|b^2|+2\Re (a\bar b)=
|a|^2+|b^2|+2|a|\,|b|\cos t\\ |a-b|^2=|a|^2+|b^2|-2\Re (a\bar b)=
|a|^2+|b^2|-2|a|\,|b|\cos t
}$$
Consider the function $f(t)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$
$$\displaylines{f(t) =|a+b|^p+|a-b|^q\\ =\left (|a|^2+|b^2|+2|a|\,|b|\cos t\right )^{q/2}+\left (|a|^2+|b^2|-2|a|\,|b|\cos t\right)^{q/2}}$$
The function $f(t)$ is even, so we may restrict to $[0,\pi].$
We have
$$\displaylines{f'(t)=-q\,|a|\,|b|\,\sin t\,\left [\left (|a|^2+|b^2|+2|a|\,|b|\cos t\right )^{q/2-1}\\ - \left (|a|^2+|b^2|-2|a|\,|b|\cos t\right )^{q/2-1}\right ]}$$
Moreover $f'(t)\le 0$ for $0\le t\le \pi/2$ and $f'(t)\ge 0$ for $\pi/2\le t\le \pi$ (as $q>2$). So the maximum is attained at $0$ or $\pi.$
Next $$f(0)=f(\pi)=(|a|+|b|)^q+\big |\, |a|-|b|\,\big |^q,\quad |a|\ge |b|$$
Summarizing, we have obtained
$$|a+b|^q+|a-b|^q\le (|a|+|b|)^q+\big |\, |a|-|b|\,\big |^q $$ thus the problem has been reduced to real numbers.

Answer (score 2):

Since the inequality in question is used primarily to derive bounds in $L_p$, namely Clarkson's inequality for $1<p<2$:
$$\Big\|\frac{f+g}{2}\Big\|^{p'}_p+\Big\|\frac{f-g}{2}\Big\|^{p'}_p\leq \Big(\frac12\big(\|f\|^p_p+\|g\|^p_p\Big)^{1/(p-1)},$$
I will present a short proof of the inequality in the OP for $\mathbb{C}$ based on  interpolation methods, namely the Riesz-Thorin interpolation theorem which I state now:

> Theorem: Let $(X,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ and $(Y,\mathscr{G},\nu)$ be $\sigma$-finite measures spaces and $1\leq p_0,p_1\leq\infty$. Suppose $T:L_{p_0}(\mu)+L_{p_1}(\mu)\rightarrow L_{q_0}(\nu)+ L_{q_1}(\nu)$ is a linear operator such that
> \begin{align}
> \|Tf\|_{q_0}&\leq M_0\|f\|_{p_0},\qquad f\in L_{p_0}(\mu)\\
> \|Tg\|_{q_1}&\leq M_1\|g\|_{q_1},\qquad g\in L_{p_1}(\mu)
> \end{align}
> For any $0<t<1$ define
> $$\frac{1}{p_t}=\frac{1-t}{p_0}+\frac{t}{p_1},\qquad \frac{1}{q_t}=\frac{1-t}{q_0}+\frac{t}{q_1}$$
> Then, $T:L_{p_t}(\mu)\rightarrow L_{q_t}(\nu)$ is a bounded linear operator and
> $$\|T\,h\|_{p_t}\leq M^{1-t}_0M^t_1\|h\|_{q_t}$$

Appealing to this theorem may appear as an overkill, however due to frat that the inequality of the OP is used primarily in the study of $L_p$ spaces, and that the interpolation theorem above is part of the curricula in integration theory, we might as well show a nice application of it. Also, elementary proof of the OP's inequality (using differentiation, or Calculus methods) are actually long and tricky, even in the real case (see for example, Hewitt, E. and Stronberg, K., *Real and Abstract Analysis*, Springer Verlag, GTM Vol 25, 1965, pp. 225-227). Finally,  versions of the Riesz-Thorin's theorem in the context of $\ell_p$ also appear in the classic book Hardy, G. et. al., *Inequalities*, Cambridge University, 1934, pp. 217-219.

---

**Proof of the OP's inequality:** Consider the operator $T$ on $\mathbb{C}^2$ defined as
$$T\begin{pmatrix}a\\b\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}a+b\\ a-b\end{pmatrix}
$$
Since all $p$-norms on Eucliean space are equivalent, we may ask ourselves what is the operator norm $\|T\|_{p,q}$ when we consider $T:(\mathbb{C},\|\,\|_p)\rightarrow(\mathbb{C},\|\;\|_q)$. Notice that for $p=2=q$
$$|a+b|^2+|a-b|^2=2(|a|+|b|^2)$$
ans so $\|T\|_{2,2}=\sqrt{2}$. On the other hand, for $p=1$ and $q=\infty$ we have $\max\{|a+b|,|a-b|\}\leq|a|+|b|$ with equality when for example $a=b=1$. Thus $\|T\|_{1,\infty}=1$. Thus, for $p_t,q_t$ with
$$\frac{1}{p_t}=\frac{1-t}{2}+t,\qquad \frac{1}{q_t}=\frac{1-t}{2}$$
$$\|T\|_{p_t,q_t}\leq 2^{(1-t)/2}$$
That is
\begin{align}
\Big(|a+b|^q+|a-b|^q\Big)^{1/q}\leq 2^{(1-t)/2}\big(|a|^p+|b|^p\big)^{1/p}\end{align}
Notice that $\frac{1}{2}<\frac{1}{p}<1$ and that $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$. Substituting $q=\frac{2}{1-t}$ yields the desired inequality
\begin{align}
|a+b|^q+|a-b|^q\leq 2 \big(|a|^p+|b|^p\big)^{q/p}=
 2 \big(|a|^p+|b|^p\big)^{q-1}\tag{1}\label{one}\end{align}

---

**Comment:** Clarkson's inequality
$$
|a+b|^q+|a-b|^q\leq 2^{q-1}(|a|^q+|b|^q),\qquad q\geq2$$
can be obtained by interpolating between $\|T\|_{2,2}$ and $\|T\|_{\infty,\infty}$; another approach is to use \eqref{one} and Hólder's inequality: Since $\frac1p+\frac1q=1$, $1<p<q$ and so,
$$
|a|^p+|b|^p=2\Big(\frac12 |a|^p\cdot1+\frac12 |b|^p\cdot1\Big)\leq 2\Big(\frac{1}{2}|a|^q+\frac{1}{2}|b|^q\Big)^{p/q}=2^{1-\tfrac{p}{q}}(|a|^q+|b|^q)^{p/q}
$$
Putting things together, we obtain
$$|a+b|^q+|a-b|^q\leq 2\big(|a|^p+|b|^p\big)^{q-1}\leq
2^{q/p}(|a|^q+|b|^q)=2^{q-1}(|a|^q+|b|^q)
$$

---

The idea of using interpolation to derive a simple proof of Clarkson's inequalities for $\mathbb{C}$ appears in the paper
Boas, R. P. Jr,, *Some Uniformly Convex Spaces*, Bull. Amer. Math. Soc. Vol.46 • No. 4 • April 1940., pp. 304-311